# my JAVA code skipping a line without any reason why

Tags: java, function

i'm doing a pac-man game in JAVA, right now the ghosts are moving (just by 1 square) **only** after pac-man moves and pac-man moving (also just by 1 square) **only** when one of the arrows on the keyboard is pressed, and i want to make the ghosts to move in constant speed no matter what (lets say for example, 2 squares per second)...
i have this loop, which basically working fine except the screen won't refresh itself:

```
while(true) {
            isGot = redG.moves(packguy.getCurrentPanel().getLoc());
            if (isGot)
                while (true)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "you lost!");
            if (steps == 2) {
                pinkG = new Ghost(panelGrid[10][14], 0, 5);
            }
            if (steps > 1) {
                isGot = pinkG.moves(packguy.getCurrentPanel().getLoc());
                if (isGot)
                    while (true)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "you lost!");
                if (steps == 3) {
                    orangeG = new Ghost(panelGrid[10][14], 0, 4);
                }
                if (steps > 2) {
                    isGot = orangeG.moves(packguy.getCurrentPanel().getLoc());
                    if (isGot)
                        while (true)
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "you lost!");
                    if (steps == 4) {
                        cyanG = new Ghost(panelGrid[10][14], 0, 6);
                    }
                    if (steps > 3) {
                        isGot = cyanG.moves(packguy.getCurrentPanel().getLoc());
                        if (isGot)
                            while (true)
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "you lost!");
                    }
                }
            }
            framePaint();
            //
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            steps++;
        }
```

the function **framePaint()** is a function i made which put on every square the thing that supposed to be in this square (rather it's ghost, pac-man himself...). First the function remove every object in each square, afterwards it is checking what's supposed to be in the square and put the match photo (which work pretty well). at the end of the function there is those lines:

```
frame.repaint();
frame.validate();
```

if im putting a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "some message");` in the line where I put the \\ the screen does refreshing when i get the message...
can you all please help me figure this out?
advanced thanks :)

Comment: Are you doing all of this on the EDT? How did you start the loop? It sounds like you're running your loop on the EDT and not letting swing/awt handle events.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a keylistener that reacts whenever a key is pressed. In that you calculate all the new positions.

Instead create a background thread that will periodically (two times per second?) calculate the positions. For the player object, use the last direction of movement to make pacman continue walking.

In the keylistener just set the direction for pacman and use that in the background thread. Whenever the background thread moved something on the screen, it shall call the component's [repaint()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) method. The Swing framework will then call paintComponent() to really draw the game.

Comment: thanks a lot! it helped me and saved me (for now... now it's time to keep the game without me knowing what i'm doing) :)